# Xamarin.Forms override EditText method is causing an infinite loop

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.entry

I have two custom entries:

- `MaxLengthEntry : Entry`
- `BannedCharactersEntry : MaxLengthEntry`

The problem is that an infinite loop occurs when the user inputs a character that is allowed and exceeds the maximum length of the entry.

The `BannedCharactersEntry` is added in XAML like so:

`<local:BannedCharactersEntry BannedCharacters="369" Text="1" Keyboard="Numeric" MaxLength="1" />`

**MaxLengthEntry** class:

```
class MaxLengthEntry : Entry
{
    public MaxLengthEntry()
    {
        base.TextChanged += EditText;
    }

    public virtual void EditText(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Entry e = sender as Entry;
        String val = e.Text;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
            return;

        if (Uppercase)
            val = val.ToUpper();

        if (MaxLength > 0 && val.Length > MaxLength)
        {
            val = val.Remove(val.Length - 1);
        }
        e.Text = val;
        Debug.WriteLine("MAX: " + val);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty UppercaseProperty = BindableProperty.Create<MaxLengthEntry, bool>(p => p.Uppercase, false);

    public bool Uppercase
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(UppercaseProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(UppercaseProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty MaxLengthProperty = BindableProperty.Create<MaxLengthEntry, int>(p => p.MaxLength, 0);

    public int MaxLength
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)GetValue(MaxLengthProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MaxLengthProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

**BannedCharactersEntry** class:

```
class BannedCharactersEntry : MaxLengthEntry
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty BannedCharactersProperty =
  BindableProperty.Create("BannedCharacters", typeof(string), typeof(BannedCharactersEntry), null);

    public string BannedCharacters
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(BannedCharactersProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BannedCharactersProperty, value); }
    }

    public BannedCharactersEntry() : base()
    {

    }

    public override void EditText(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.EditText(sender, args);

        Entry e = sender as Entry;
        String val = e.Text;

        Debug.WriteLine("BANNED: " + val);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
            return;

        foreach (char c in BannedCharacters)
        {
            if (val[val.Length - 1] == c)
            {
                val = val.Remove(val.Length - 1);
                break;
            }
        }

        e.Text = val;
    }
}
```

The initial value of the BannedCharactersEntry is 1. I then press 2. 
The output goes like this:

MAX: 1
BANNED: 12 
MAX: 1
BANNED: 1 
MAX: 1
BANNED: 12 
MAX: 1
BANNED: 1 
etc...

I don't know why the `EditText` method is continuously called or why the *BANNED* output is ever 12.

Comment: Your Banned character check changes the text and in turn calls the edit text.

Comment: I thought that may be the case. Any ideas on how I should restructure my classes / methods to do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very simple. Thanks to Rohit for pointing me in the right direction!

`EditText` method in the **BannedCharactersEntry** class:

```
protected override void EditText(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Entry e = sender as Entry;
        String val = e.Text;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
            return;

        foreach (char c in BannedCharacters)
        {
            if (val[val.Length - 1] == c)
            {
                val = val.Remove(val.Length - 1);
                e.Text = val;
                return;
            }
        }

        base.EditText(sender, args);
    }
```

All I needed to do was return from the method if a banned character was input because `MaxLength` will never be exceeded if the banned character is removed upon input.

Otherwise, `MaxLengthEntry.EditText` is called via `base.EditText`. I don't need to worry about an infinite loop either because the text is changed OR `base.EditText` is called. Never both.

Answer (score 0):

You can just Bind your `Text` property to your viewmodel and remove the character from the ViewModel property.

Also instead of `override` you can try to attach to the event of `TextChanged` in your `BannedCharacterEntry`.

Also you are calling the `base.EditText` at the start of your override function which will change the text, but on the continued execution your are using the original value instead of the changed value. You can call the `base.EditText` at the end of your overridden function.

And, you need not have your `EditText` method as public. It can be made private. If you are attaching to it in both the constructors.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean in the first line. I think I need an example to understand. Also, I tried the base.EditText at the end of my method but the infinite loop still occurred.

Comment: Try without overriding. Attaching to the event again. Both the event handlers would fire.

Comment: Still got an infinite loop assuming I understood correctly. I removed base.EditText and removed the base() constructor from BannedCharactersEntry. Then I added TextChanged += EditText to the BannedCharactersEntry constructor.